# SQL: Getting the min date of a series of dates partitioning by if previous date is more than 1 day ago

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, window-functions

I have a data import which happens every week and when it starts, lasts a couple of days. As a result, in the date column, I have multiple dates for each data import. I would like to get the min date of each import. Is this possible in SQL? Specifically, in Google BigQuery. Example:

```
date    desired_output
4/25/17 4/25/17
4/26/17 4/25/17
4/27/17 4/25/17
5/2/17  5/2/17
5/3/17  5/2/17
5/10/17 5/10/17
5/16/17 5/16/17
5/17/17 5/16/17
5/23/17 5/23/17
5/24/17 5/23/17
5/30/17 5/30/17
5/31/17 5/30/17
6/5/17  6/5/17
6/6/17  6/6/17
```

Comment: do you have any field that can identify rows belonging to same import? or whole table is a one import?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't. Going forward, we are adding this field, but I wanted to run some analysis on the historical data without having to manually rename the dates.

Comment: so how you plan to distinguish between different imports? you should provide some logic for this. and show some simplified data example with expected output. as long as you have it it should be super simple then

Comment: oh, i totally missed it  - you have the logic in post title

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can identify groups of dates that are in order sequentially -- this is a gaps and islands problem.  Perhaps this will do what you want:

```
select date,
       min(date) over (partition by date_add(date, interval - seqnum_d day)) as desired_output
from (select t.*,
             dense_rank() over (order by date) as seqnum_d
      from t
     ) t
```

The date arithmetic identifies sequences of dates by subtracting a sequence -- voila!  The result is a constant.

Note:  This assumes that sequences of dates have gaps.

Also, I used `dense_rank()` so it can handle multiple entries on a single date.